# How do I join a channel on Freenode with Empathy?

Tags: empathy, irc

I have empathy already installed but am not sure how to configure it to join the channel at http://www.ape-project.org.  I do not have a password or login name yet to properly configure the channel with Empathy and when I click "Join our IRC Channel" firefox comes back with an error stating:

> Firefox doesn't know how to open this address, because the protocol (irc) isn't associated with any program.

What can I do to join this (freenode) channel?

**UPDATE 1**
Using Empathy Version 2.23.1
When viewing accounts click "Add..." 
Protocol: "IRC"
Network: "freenode"
create new nickname, password, and real name.

Then went back to ape-project.org link and click "Join our IRC Channel" again.  It brings my Empathy contact list to the foreground but nothing happens...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Empathy wouldn't do anything when I click on the link (won't bring up an input box for me to enter /join #ape-project or anything.  And since I can't get freenode server to bring anything up either I just started using xchat - which works perfectly fine.

Comment: please reconsider the "correct answer" flag

Answer (score 7):

Basically the channel name for the ape-project is #ape-project. So after joining to freenode on empathy Just do

```
/join #ape-project
```

on text input field.

Comment: "after joining to freenode on empathy " <- can you expand on this?

Answer (score 6):

In ubuntu 13.04, you should add the `account-plugin-irc` package to use IRC:

```
sudo apt-get install account-plugin-irc
```

After that you'll have an IRC account option under "Online Accounts".

Comment: He's asking about Empathy, and that package only works with Geany, no?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Geany, but the above solution most definitely worked for me. Previously when I tried to add an IRC account to empathy, it simply took me to the "Online Accounts" system dialog. After I installed `account-plugin-irc`, empathy connected to the freenode account I defined in Online Accounts. I think this process has changed in the later releases of ubuntu, hence the caveat for 13.04.

Comment: Mm... found out that that package is included in the universe repository and depends on `telepaty-idle` which is the one I'm accustomed seeing. It seems that only include `/usr/share/accounts/providers/` files so Gnome environment knows about who provides `irc://`. But for empathy seems that the shortest route is `telepathy-idle`.

Answer (score 3):

In empathy "help" menu, you can see that it's easy to setup your IRC.

First you have to **add a new account for IRC**. You can choose networks provided by empathy or add new network (e.g: irc.freenode.net)

Don't forget to add your **nickname**, not only "realname".

To join a chat room, go to Room > Join (shortcut Ctrl+J) and input the room name. (e.g: #ape-project)

**NB: If you can't create IRC account, try `sudo apt-get install telepathy-idle`**

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Gnome 3 (for my sins) which gives me an 'Empathy' app icon in the top panel of my screen when the Empathy window is active.  Left clicking the app name gives the main app menu, which has a 'Rooms...' entry with a 'Join..' item.  This brings up a dialog I can use to join a room.

Another way was that I tried to join FreeNode using a nick which is password protected.  Empathy raised a notification (hidden off the bottom of the screen, I really don't know what these gnome 3 guys are smoking) so if I hover my mouse at the bottom of the screen for a few seconds, click the notification (possibly right click and choose Open from the menu) I find an Empathy chat session with the name of my server (in my case 'Freenode') into which I can type "/join #whatever".